# How can I include a file with a NuGet package, and then add that file to a project when the NuGet package is installed?

Tags: nuget

I have a project that includes 2 files:

1. ThisProject.config.example
2. ThisProject.xsd

This project is packaged as a Nuget package, which is then added to other projects. When this happens I would like these files copied into the projects. The user then copies `ThisProject.config.example` to `ThisProject.config` and edits that file.

I understand that within a `.nuspec` file there are two ways to include files. These are:

```
<files>
  <file src="ThisProject.config.example" target="ThisProject.config.example" />
  <file src="ThisProject.xsd" target="ThisProject.xsd"/>
</files>
```

Doing this, I see that when I install the package into the `/packages` folder that the files have been copied over. Which is good. However, then it would seem that I need to use a `.ps` script to add them to the project that the nuget package is installed to?

I haven't tried this yet, but according to [THIS](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html) link, there are three scripts that can be incorporated into NuGet packages:

1. Init.ps1
2. Install.ps1
3. Uninstall.ps1

But No. 2 and 3 are obsolete from VS 2017 onwards? The link that is provided for explanation points to information on MSBuild. But there is no explicit information on flatfile types so far as I can see.

Then. Supposedly there is a `<contentFiles>` tag. But according to [THIS](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) post (NuGet blog) only works when a package is added to certain project types. And does not work with `package.config` files...

What is the expected way of adding a file to a project from a NuGet package??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if you put files within certain folder structures that they are implicitly added to the package and also added to the project root directtory. However I still have not found a way to add the files as items in the project itself. this is an example of the .nuspec file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    ...
    <tags>some tags</tags>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles\any\any\config\name.example" target="content\name.example" />
    <file src="contentFiles\any\any\config\name.xsd" target="content\name.xsd"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

The MS docs mention it is useful to define both files and contentFiles. I think the requirement is that the nuget package has a folder `content`, in which files are transferred to the project directory

Comment: Actually. sometimes file references are added to .sln files, and sometimes not. don't know why, or if I'm doing something different that results in different outcomes.